# Javascript function undefined when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this on my cshtml:

```
<button  onclick="save()" id="fundersSave" data-action="save-funder" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">@Strings.Buttons_Save</button>
```

Then on my cshtml I have added the javascript:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function save(){
        var $form = $('.fancybox-inner').find('[data-area="funder-detail"]');

        $form.on('click', '[data-action="save-funder"]', function () {
            alert();
            var selected1 = $form.find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
            if ($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length == 0) {
                parent.$.fancybox.close();
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("txtFunder").value = selected1;
                parent.$.fancybox.close();
            }
        });
}
    </script>
</body>
```

When I click on the [Save] button, I get undefined error.

Comment: where do you define the `save()` function that you have in that `onclick` attribute in your HTML?

Comment: What does `var $form` return

Comment: I find it suspicious that you just added it :p  If you still get an undefined error, try opening the console and getting more information about it.

Comment: And why do you have `$form.on('click', '[data-action="save-funder"]', function () {` and `onclick="save()"`? - use one or the other

Comment: Mind saying what the exact error message is?

Comment: Here is the error thrown when I am debugging. Apologies, as I am new to JS. 

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'save' is undefined

Comment: Is this code changed in any way? is this the real code?

Comment: Your button already has an `id` attribute. Remove the `onclick="save()"` and change the script to `$('#fundersSave').click(function() { // do something });`

Answer (score 0):

If you included your jquery librairy at the bottom of your _layout, move it just after the body tag !

Comment: Why downvote my answer ? try it, that ll adjust your problem;